# Find $f(x,y)$ if each level curve $f(x,y)=C$ is a circle centered at the origin and having radius

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Find $f(x,y)$ if each level curve $f(x,y)=C$ is a circle centered at the origin and having radius

(a) $C$

(b) $C^2$

(c) $\sqrt{C}$

(d) $\ln C$.

I am not good at this...

Answer (score 1):

There don't seem to be many options:

$$f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-D\;,\;\;0<D\;\;\text{a constant, and then for example:}$$

$$(a)\;\;\;f(x,y)=C\iff x^2+y^2=C+D\iff D=0$$

$$(b)\;\;\;f(x,y)=C\iff x^2+y^2=C+D=C^2\iff D=C(C-1)$$

and etc. Now you try the other ones.

Comment: I disagree; there are many functions with circles as level sets, not just paraboloids (any radial function works). Further, your calculation for (a) implies $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ in which case $f(x,y) = C^2$ on the circle of radius $C$, and in case (b), the "constant" $D$ is defined in terms of $C$, which changes with the level surface.

Comment: @BaronVT, I agree with you: my example is way to narrow and, besides , this, should have taken into account that radius $\;C\ge 0\;$ means that $\;x^2+y^2=C^2\;$ , not $\;C\;$ as I wrote. I shall leave for a while the answer as it is for people to compare. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The circle of radius $r$ consists of the points $(x,y)$ such that $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$. The level curve is the set of points $(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y)$ has the given value.

Combining these statements, what this means is that

(a) $x^2 + y^2 = C^2$ if and only if $f(x,y) = C$.

You want to write a formula for $f(x,y)$ in terms of $x,y$. So do whatever you need to in order to set those two equations equal to each other. In particular,

$$
(f(x,y))^2 = C^2 = x^2 + y^2
$$

so $f(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.

Proceed similarly with the others, start (b) by noting $x^2 + y^2 = C^4$ if and only if $f(x,y) = C$, etc.

Comment: Okay for b) I got $C=f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)^{(1/4)}$ and for c) I got $C=f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ and for d) I got $C=f(x,y)=e^{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

Comment: Yep, those are all correct. Nice work.